# The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type X

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I need to load multiple Item Collections from db asynchronously. If I encapsule the query in a Task.Run() I keep getting this exception.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 
-----
en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.GetEntityEntry(Object entity)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.ClearCollectionOrRef(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, RelationshipNavigation navigation, Boolean doCascadeDelete)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.AddToLocalCache(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean applyConstraints)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedTarget, Boolean applyConstraints, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean allowModifyingOtherEndOfRelationship, Boolean forceForeignKeyChanges)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean applyConstraints)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.set_ReferenceValue(IEntityWrapper value)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.SetEntityKey(EntityKey value, Boolean forceFixup)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupEntityReferenceToPrincipal(EntityReference relatedEnd, EntityKey foreignKey, Boolean setIsLoaded, Boolean replaceExistingRef)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys(Boolean replaceAddedRefs, EntitySetBase restrictTo)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys(EntityEntry newEntry, Boolean replaceAddedRefs)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   en lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   en System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   en System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   en AMC.OM.App.Views.Logistica.EntradaMercancia.PopUpCrearIncidencia.PopUpCrearIncidenciaViewModel.<SetViewModelPropertiesAsync>b__62_1() en D:\Proyectos .NET\AMC\OperationManager\Code\App\AMC.OM.App\Views\Logistica\EntradaMercancia\PopUpCrearIncidencia\PopUpCrearIncidenciaViewModel.cs:línea 247
```

It doesn't break the execution while loading the data. Just when I call the `await`. But the exception is being thrown many times

I have tested querying it synchronously and it works but the window takes +40s to load.
Apparently it's because EF loads the lazy elements synchronously so it's possible that the lazy relations are being loaded before the parent itself...

```cs
/*
This throws the exceptions
*/
FillList = new Task[2];
FillList[(int)Tasks.PedidoCompra] = Task.Run(() =>
{
     PedidosCompra = new ObservableCollection<WM_Pedido_Proveedor>(Context.WM_Pedido_Proveedor.Where(x => x.CompanyId == cId).ToList());
});
FillList[(int)Tasks.Lote] = Task.Run(() =>
{
     Lotes = new ObservableCollection<WM_Lote>(Context.WM_Lote.Where(x => x.CompanyId == cId).ToList());
});

//... When the user press the button using that collection
var listTask = FillList[(int)Tasks.PedidoCompra];
if (!listTask.IsCompleted)
     await listTask;
```

```cs
/*
This works (the window takes +40s to load)
*/
PedidosCompra = new ObservableCollection<WM_Pedido_Proveedor>(Context.WM_Pedido_Proveedor.Where(x => x.CompanyId == cId).ToList());
Lotes = new ObservableCollection<WM_Lote>(Context.WM_Lote.Where(x => x.CompanyId == cId).ToList());
//...
```

I wanted to load the data asynchronously and freeze the app only when the user needs the data and is not yet loaded, but apparently its loading the lazy relations before the parent element and can't map it properly.